# Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException at Conn.Connexion.insertUtilisateur(Connexion.java:50)

Tags: java, sql, netbeans

I want to insert some informations in my dataBase "sqlserver" via NetBeans!!!the connection is good but don't know what's the pb,realy this pb make me crazy!!!!!!!

Please help me!!!!

```
CODE:
package Conn;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.*;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

/**
*
1. @author Nadia
*/
public class Connexion {

java.sql.Connection C;

private Connection C1;
String Nom;
    String Adresse;
    String MDP;
    String VMDP;
/**
 * Constructeur`enter code here`
 */
public Connexion() {
    //this.connection=ConnexionBDD.getInstance();

        try{
Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
      C1=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost\\A:1433databaseName=Authentif","sa","sqlserver");
Statement  stmt = C1.createStatement();
}

 catch(Exception e){}

}

//*************Insertion Utilisateur
```

//  public int insertUtilisateur(UserIdentit utilisateur) {

```
public void insertUtilisateur(String Nom,String Adresse,String MDP,String VMDP) {

    PreparedStatement pst;
try {




**pst = C1.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO Authentif.dbo.tab_authentif      (Nomc,Adressec,MDP,VMDP)"+"VALUES(?,?,?,?)");** *(ligne 50)*

        pst.setString(1,Nom);
                    pst.setString(2,Adresse);
                    pst.setString(3,MDP);
                    pst.setString(4,VMDP);
                    int res=pst.executeUpdate();
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,ex.getMessage());
    }
```

}
   }

Answer (score 0):

Follow the SQL Server [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378428.aspx)

You need to add a semi-colon before the database key-value pair:

```
jdbc:sqlserver://localhost\\A:1433;databaseName=Authentif
                                  ^
```

This is causing the `Connection` to be `null` here. No exceptions message appears as the exception is being silently caught. Add some form of notification such as a `printStackTrace` call. Finally, catch the most specific exception, in this case, an `SQLException`. This allows the application to handle database specific exceptions.